# Spark (2.3.0) History Server - How to get Execution Plan from REST API

Tags: rest, apache-spark

If I go to the Spark (2.3.0) History server web UI at a URL such as follows:

`http://sparkhistoryserver.domain.com:99999/history/application_1539123073456_57898/SQL/execution/?id=0`

I can see a visual representation of the DAG. Scrolling down a bit further, I see a "Details" tab which, when expanded, displays text information on the `== Parsed Logical Plan ==`.

The question is, how can I retrieve this parsed logical plan via REST API for further parsing and analysis purposes?

Here's the link to the 2.3.0 REST API docs but I didnt see any reference to which endpoint could provide this level of information: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/monitoring.html

Note, I know the information can be parsed out of the html returned from the url I provided above but doesnt seem as clean as an API that returns the results in json format.

Comment: found something?

Comment: anyone found anything for this?